# Como fixar uma tabela HTML sem permitir redimensionamento

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap-3, table

Tenho um calendário de eventos onde o usuário clica sobre uma data e abre um modal para fazer o cadastramento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém quando um agendamento é incluído, ele fica dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observem que no dia 03, apesar de ter limitado os caracteres com o `substr()` no PHP e colocado o `width:50px`, ele *empurrou* a outra coluna. Vejam como está o código da tabela:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th scope="col" style="background-color: #F5F5F5; text-align: center; width: 50px"><abbr title="<?php echo $nome_dia[1]; ?>"><?php echo $nome_abreviado_dia[1]; ?></abbr></th>
<th scope="col" style="background-color: #F5F5F5; text-align: center; width: 50px"><abbr title="<?php echo $nome_dia[2]; ?>"><?php echo $nome_abreviado_dia[2]; ?></abbr></th>
<th scope="col" style="background-color: #F5F5F5; text-align: center; width: 50px"><abbr title="<?php echo $nome_dia[3]; ?>"><?php echo $nome_abreviado_dia[3]; ?></abbr></th>
<th scope="col" style="background-color: #F5F5F5; text-align: center; width: 50px"><abbr title="<?php echo $nome_dia[4]; ?>"><?php echo $nome_abreviado_dia[4]; ?></abbr></th>
<th scope="col" style="background-color: #F5F5F5; text-align: center; width: 50px"><abbr title="<?php echo $nome_dia[6]; ?>"><?php echo $nome_abreviado_dia[6]; ?></abbr></th>
<th scope="col" style="background-color: #F5F5F5; text-align: center; width: 50px"><abbr title="<?php echo $nome_dia[5]; ?>"><?php echo $nome_abreviado_dia[5]; ?></abbr></th>
<th scope="col" style="background-color: #F5F5F5; text-align: center; width: 50px"><abbr title="<?php echo $nome_dia[7]; ?>"><?php echo $nome_abreviado_dia[7]; ?></abbr></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<?php
$coluna = 1;
foreach ($dias as $i => $dia) {
    if ($coluna == 1) {
        $tabela .= '<tr>';
    }
    $class = $i < $posicao_antes || $i >= $posicao_depois ? ' class="extra"' : '';
    if($dia == date("j")){
       $style = "background-color: #F5F5F5";
    }else{
      $style = "";
    }
    if($dia == 0){
    $tabela .= "<td style=\"".$style."\"></td>";
    }else{
    $diaCadastro = date("Y")."-".date("m")."-".$dia;
    $visualizar = $metodos->mostrarEventos($idCliente,$diaCadastro);
    if($visualizar[0] > 0){
      $tabela .= "<td style=\"width: 50px; cursor: pointer; height: 150px;".$style."\" id=\"idTDAlterar\" data-id=\"{$visualizar[1]->IdAgenda}\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#modalAlterar\">";
    }else{
      $tabela .= "<td style=\"width: 50px; cursor: pointer; height: 150px;".$style."\" id=\"idTD\" data-id=\"{$diaCadastro}\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#modal\">";
    }
    $tabela .= $dia."<br>";
    $icone = ($visualizar[0] > 0)?"<i class=\"far fa-calendar-check fa-lg\"></i> ":null;
    $tabela .= $icone . substr(strip_tags($visualizar[1]->Agenda),0,20);
    $tabela .= "</td>";
   }
    $coluna += 1;
    if ($coluna == 8) {
        $tabela .= '</tr>';
        $coluna = 1;
    }
}
echo $tabela;
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: não seria o caso de apenas utilizar `overflow` ?

Comment: Olha se isso resolver, coloca `text-overflow: ellipsis` nas `TD` e ve se te atende, link sobre essa propriedade CSS https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem primeiro de tudo eu recomendo fazer uma folha de estilo (CSS) já que todas suas `TAG` da tabela tem as mesmas propriedades, fazendo uma class é muito mais fácil de encorporar o código e depois fazer manutenção no mesmo

```
<th scope="col" class="tabela"><abbr title="<?php echo $nome_dia[7]; ?>"><?php echo $nome_abreviado_dia[7]; ?></abbr></th>

.tabela{
background-color: #F5F5F5; 
text-align: center; 
width: 50px
}
```

Segundo já tentou usar `TABLE-LAYOUT: fixed` em toda sua tabela?

na sua `<tr>` coloque o `TABLE-LAYOUT: fixed` para "prender toda sua tabela"

recomendo leitura:

- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_table-layout